# How to configure bitbucket cloud default groups for a new repo

Tags: bitbucket

I am trying to configure bitbucket cloud so as to include only administrators on a new repository. I don't know who/how this account I am working with was setup, but when I new repo is created it has 10 groups automatically added with lots of overlap.

A 20 minute search on atlassian's website yields a lot of information about groups in general, but not how the defaults are set

Answer (score 3):

A bit late

Default groups are defined within the "Create/Edit group" modal.

If you want to remove all unwanted groups you should go to your team settings and select **User groups**. Select the group you want to remove from defaults and then select **Edit**. BitBucket will show a modal with the group settings and there you should change **Default repository access** to **None**.

You can find that [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/organize-your-team-into-user-groups-665225542.html#Organizeyourteamintousergroups-accessUpdateagroup'srepositoryaccesspermissions)